# How can i set multiple response type in RestApi call

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, yaml, swagger

I do have one API call in which I have to return the byte format of the certificate and the response type is `octet/stream`. 
However, if there is an error that occurs the error will be in `application/JSON`. How can I set both response types in **swagger/rest-client**? 
For now,The contract is defined in swagger and I have to manually select content type in rest clients for each of the scenarios to see the response?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the response type following this approach:

```
    @GetMapping("/public/download")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (fixedToken.equals(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))) {
            Resource file = fileStorageService.loadFileAsResource("fil-name-here", "folder");
            return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"").body(file);
        }

        //Your custom response
        Map response = new HashMap();
        response.put("code", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        response.put("message", "some message");

        return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
```

In this example, if the token is valid, the API responds with the bytes. Otherwise, you will see this (as JSON):

```
{
  "code": 403,
  "message": "some message"
}
```

Important here: `@ResponseBody`

This is on spring-boot side, now if you need a static swagger file (.yaml) you need something like this:

```
paths:
  /{file_name}:
    get:
      tags:
      - "your app tag"
      summary: "Download"
      description: "Get file content"
      operationId: "operationNameOnSpringBoot"
      parameters:
      - name: "file_name"
        in: "path"
        description: "file name"
        required: true
        schema:
          type: "string"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
          content:
            application/octet-stream:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
        404:
          description: "Not found"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/your_error_schema"
```

Comment: I have used swagger api for the error generation.How this code is going to work with swagger ?

Comment: You have the tag "spring-boot" in your post, so the swagger file can be generated, but in case you need to have a static file, check the second part of the answer, just add more entries (400, 406, etc) and provide the response type...